# Five9 API python wrapper - runReport

Tags: python, api, five9

Has anyone used the python wrapper for the *Five9 API*?

I'm trying to run one of our custom reports through the API but am unsure how to pass the time criteria.

If the report is already built:
Is there a way to run it without passing criteria?

It seems like this should be enough (since the report is already built):

```
client.configuration.runReport(folderName='Shared Reports', reportName='Test report')
```

But it didn't work as expected.
What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. You can probably get fancier with a while loop checking if the report is done but this isn't time sensitive.

```
from five9 import Five9
import time

client = Five9('username','password')
start = '2019-08-01T00:00:00.000'
end = '2019-08-29T00:00:00.000'
criteria = {'time':{'end':end, 'start':start}}
identifier = client.configuration.runReport(folderName='SharedReports',reportName='reportname',criteria=criteria)
time.sleep(15)
get_results = client.configuration.getReportResult(identifier)
```